# Calculate multiple prices in XML file and import only one in WP All Import

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having trouble in XML file that contains about 10k products and i want to import them to woocommerse with WP All import. There is one node for price i.e.

```
 <price>92.50</price>
```

, one node for currency

```
 <currency>EUR</currency>
```

, but problem is 3 values for currencies **"EUR"**, **"USD"** and **"BGN"**. I want to import only BGN currency and others to calculate and convert to BGN. Rate for EUR is 1 EUR = 1.9583BGN, 1 USD = 1.762BGN. How to import only BGN price and calculate others to BGN in WP All Import?

I use this function in Function editor in WP All Import:

```
<?php
 $currency = array( "EUR", "USD", "BGN" ); 
function rate_price( $price = null, $multiplier_eur = 2, $multiplier_usd = 1 ) {
if ( $currency[0] ) {
// strip any extra characters from price
return $price * $multiplier_eur;
} else if ( $currency[1] ) {
    return $price * $multiplier_usd;
} else {
    return $price;
}
}
?>
```

and this for Regular Price (BGN)
xPath in wooCommerce add-on,

```
[rate_price({price[1]},"1.9583","1.762")]
```

but it's not working, showing me only the original price for product, 92.50 EUR in the case, please, HELP!

Comment: You can use XPath to find the correct currency item along with the price. Have a go with that and if you still have problems create a question with the code a segment of the XML and what problems you are having to it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Nigel Ren in the comment, xpath is the way to go in these cases.

Something along these lines:

```
$prods = "<units>"
        . "<unit><price>10.00</price><currency>EUR</currency></unit>"
        . "<unit><price>20.00</price><currency>BGN</currency></unit>"
        . "<unit><price>30.00</price><currency>USD</currency></unit>"
        . "</units>";
$prod_xml = simplexml_load_string($prods);
$prod_dat = $prod_xml->xpath('//unit');

function rate_price($price, $cur) {
    if ($cur == "USD") {
        return $price * 3;
    } else if ($cur == "EUR") {
        return $price * 2;
    } else {
        return $price * 1;
    }
}

foreach ($prod_dat as $datum) {
    $unit_price = $datum->xpath('.//price')[0];
    $unit_cur = $datum->xpath('.//currency')[0];
    $final_price = rate_price($unit_price, $unit_cur);
    echo "Unit Currency: " . $unit_cur . " Orig unit price: " . $unit_price . " BGN price: " . $final_price;
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Output:

```
Unit Currency: EUR Orig unit price: 10.00 BGN price: 20
Unit Currency: BGN Orig unit price: 20.00 BGN price: 20
Unit Currency: USD Orig unit price: 30.00 BGN price: 90
```